# Preserving Lebesgue Measurability

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

So from what I've been in reading, if f is a homeomorphism then f does not  preserve Lebesgue measurability for some E, i.e, E is measurable iff f(E) is measurable.

Does this change if the inverse of f sends Lebesgue Zero Sets to Lebesgue Zero Sets?

Comment: What about $f(x) = x$?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise it is a minor, but extremely common, abuse of language to say "$f$ does not preserve property $X$" when one means "$f$ does not necessarily preserve property $X$". That is what OP means.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $c(x)$ denote the Cantor function on $[0,1]$ and consider $f: [0,1] \to [0,2]$ given by $f(x) = c(x) + x$.

Comment: That's what I thought but there is a problem in Real Analysis by C. Pugh which says to show that it does.